# propertyIsEnumerable(x) versus x in

Tags: javascript, properties, enumeration, enumerable

I encountered the method `o.propertyIsEnumerable(x)` in Javascript code. I understand it as a synonym for the `x in o` construct. Is there a difference? If so, could you show when to use the first construct and when to use the second construct on some practical example?

```
var o = {};
o.x = 1;
o.y = 2;

if ("x" in o) {
 // some code
}

if (o.propertyIsEnumerable(x)) {
  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to work out things like this is to follow the algorithms in the spec. This is what it tells us about [`propertyIsEnumerable`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.7):

> - Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of *O* passing *P* as the argument.
> - If desc is undefined, return false.
> - Return the value of *desc*.[[Enumerable]].

As you can see, it will call the [`[[GetOwnProperty]]` internal method](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.7) of the object in question. That simply returns the value of the specified property from the *object itself* (not from anything in its prototype chain).

Now let's have a look at the [`in` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.7):

> Return the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of *rval* with argument ToString(lval).

And if you look at the [`[[HasProperty]]` internal method](http://jsfiddle.net/AjaGS/):

> Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of *O* with property name *P*

And here you can see the difference. The `in` operator results in the use of the [`[[GetProperty]]` internal method][4], instead of the `[[GetOwnProperty]]` method, and that means it will find properties on objects down the prototype chain.

The other major difference is that you can define non-enumerable properties on an object (with the `Object.defineProperty` method). If you define a non-enumerable property, it *will* be returned by the `in` operator, but obviously not by the `propertyIsEnumerable` method. Here's a [fiddle that demonstrates the difference](http://jsfiddle.net/AjaGS/).

Answer (score 0):

This takes into account prototyped properties and doesn't give consideration to enumerability.

```
if (x in o)
```

The other does not. It only looks at "own" properties.

```
if (o.propertyIsEnumerable(x))
```